# Separate a text file with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have the following sample file:

```
evtlog.161202.002609.debugevtlog.161201.162408.debugevtlog.161202.011046.debugevtlog.161202.002809.debugevtlog.161201.160035.debugevtlog.161201.155140.debugevtlog.161201.232156.debugevtlog.161201.145017.debugevtlog.161201.154816.debug
```

I want to separate the string and add a newline after matching "debug" like this:

```
evtlog.161202.002609.debug
evtlog.161201.162408.debug
```

So far I tried almost everything with sed, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

```
sed  's/debug/{G}' latest_evtlogs.out
sed  '/debug/i "SAD"' latest_evtlogs.out
```

etc...
`sed  's/debug/\n/g' latest_evtlogs.out` doesn't work when I add it as a pipe in the script , but it does when I run it manually.

Here's how I generate the file:

```
printf $(ls -l $EVTLOG_PATH/evtlog|tail -n 10|awk  '{printf $8 , "%s\n\n"}'|sed 's/debug/\n/g') >> latest_evtlogs.out
```

Initially I wanted to just add newline with awk, but it doesn't work either.
Any ideas why I can't separate the string with a newline ?

I'm using :

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.10 (lenny)
Release:        5.0.10
Codename:       lenny
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't doing a lot of processing you don't need to?  You're using `ls -l` to get a full listing of the directory, then using Awk to extract only the filename and printing it without a newline, then trying to add back the newlines.   Why doesn't the simpler "script" `ls $EVTLOG_PATH/evtlog | tail -n 10 >> latest_evtlogs.out` do what you want?

Comment: @K.A Buhr ,I tried it and it returns again a single string.

Comment: The `awk` command that was used to generate the output file is incorrect.  The format string should be the first parameter: `awk  '{printf "%s\n\n", $8}'`.  As @K. A. Buhr suggested, it would be better to use `ls` instead of `ls -l` because then there would be no need to use `awk`.

Comment: Maybe you are actually using `somevar=$(long_command); echo $somevar`. In this case, try `somevar=$(long_command); echo "$somevar"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers.I finally did it like this :

```
echo $(ls -l $EVTLOG_PATH/evtlog|tail -n 10|awk  '{printf $8 , "%s\n\n"}'|sed 's/debug/&\n/g')  > temp.out

sed 's/ /\n/g' /share/sqa/dumps/5314577631/checks/temp.out > latest_evtlogs.out
```

It's not at all elegant, but it finally works.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a new line after `debug`:

```
sed 's/debug/&\n/g' file
```

Note `&` prints back the matched text, so it is a way to print "debug" back.

This returns:

```
evtlog.161202.002609.debug
evtlog.161201.162408.debug
evtlog.161202.011046.debug
evtlog.161202.002809.debug
evtlog.161201.160035.debug
evtlog.161201.155140.debug
evtlog.161201.232156.debug
evtlog.161201.145017.debug
evtlog.161201.154816.debug
```

Comment: No I still get the same :  evtlog.161202.052817.debugevtlog.161201.212509.debugevtlog.161202.061126.debugevtlog.161202.062853.debugevtlog.161201.210226.d ebugevtlog.161201.205214.debugevtlog.161202.043057.debugevtlog.161201.205053.debugevtlog.161201.204846.debugevtlog.161201.211047.debugevtlog.161201.205132.debugevtlog.161201.205527.debugevtlog.161201.205217.debugevtlog.161202.043335.debugevtlog.161202.045555.debug

Comment: @VeselinIvanov sorry in comments we cannot understand such outputs. Better update your question indicatin what is your goal, since it looks like this is a part of a long pipeline

Comment: sorry it seems unreadable.What I mean is it's still a single string and there's no change in the output.

Comment: @VeselinIvanov basically, I would follow the comment you got in the question: just use `ls` and `tail`, since parsing the output of ls as you are doing now is very fragile

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you are using the output of `sed` in a command expansion. In this context your shell will replace all newlines with spaces. The spaces are then used to do the word splitting, so that `printf` sees each line as a separate argument, interpreting the first line as the format argument and ignoring the rest as there are `printf`-placeholders in the format.

It should work if you drop the outer `printf $()` from your command and just redirect the output from your pipeline to your file:

```
ls -l $EVTLOG_PATH/evtlog|tail -n 10|awk  '{printf $8 , "%s\n\n"}'|sed 's/debug/\n/g' >> latest_evtlogs.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **Perl** is *"happier"* than **sed** on your system:

```
perl -pe 's/debug/&\n/g' < YourLogFile
```

Answer (score 0):

`G`et will append what is in the hold buffer unto the pattern space (Usually just the current line read from the input file) So this cannot be used.

`i`nsert will print the specified text to standard output. So this cannot be used.

What you you want to to replace all `debug` with `debug^J`, where `^J` is a newline, dependent on the sed version, you can either do:

```
sed 's/debug/&\n/g' input_file
```

But `\n` is - afaik - not strictly specified in POSIX sed. One can however use c strings:

```
sed 's/debug/&'$'\n''/g' input_file
```

Or a multi line string:

```
sed 's/debug/&\
/g' input_file
```